# SQL Server 2014 - Use previous value when date not present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I asked a similar question yesterday but I was not very good in my description of what I wanted. This will be far clearer.

Lead/Lag is not getting me what I need. Its close, but not enough.
Using SQL Server 2014 for client, actual server built on SQL 2012.

Here is my code:
Creating Team Table

```
CREATE TABLE ##TeamTable
    ([UserID] varchar(50), [CurrentTeam] varchar(5), [ChangeDate] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO ##TeamTable
    ([UserID], [CurrentTeam], [ChangeDate])
VALUES
    ('User1', 'Team1', '6/1/2016'),
    ('User1', 'Team2', '9/1/2016'),
    ('User1', 'Team3', '12/1/2016'),
    ('User2', 'Team1', '4/1/2016'),
    ('User2', 'Team2', '10/1/2016'),
    ('User2', 'Team3', '11/1/2016');
```

Now to create data table I need to join to

```
CREATE TABLE ##DataTable
    ([UserID] varchar(50), Month_sk datetime, Media varchar(50), NCO int)
INSERT INTO ##DataTable
    ([UserID] , Month_sk , Media , NCO )
VALUES
    ('User1', '2016-06-01 00:00:00', 'Fax', 100),
    ('User1', '2016-06-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 120),
    ('User1', '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 90),
    ('User1', '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100),
    ('User1', '2016-08-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 150),
    ('User1', '2016-08-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100),
    ('User1', '2016-09-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 100),
    ('User1', '2016-09-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 120),
    ('User1', '2016-10-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 90),
    ('User1', '2016-10-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100),
    ('User1', '2016-11-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 150),
    ('User1', '2016-11-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100),
    ('User1', '2016-12-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 150),
    ('User1', '2016-12-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100),
    ('User2', '2016-04-01 00:00:00', 'Fax', 100),
    ('User2', '2016-04-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 120),
    ('User2', '2016-05-01 00:00:00', 'Fax', 100),
    ('User2', '2016-05-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 120),
    ('User2', '2016-06-01 00:00:00', 'Fax', 100),
    ('User2', '2016-06-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 120),
    ('User2', '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 90),
    ('User2', '2016-07-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100),
    ('User2', '2016-08-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 150),
    ('User2', '2016-08-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100),
    ('User2', '2016-09-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 100),
    ('User2', '2016-09-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 120),
    ('User2', '2016-10-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 90),
    ('User2', '2016-10-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100),
    ('User2', '2016-11-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 150),
    ('User2', '2016-11-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100),
    ('User2', '2016-12-01 00:00:00', 'Voice', 150),
    ('User2', '2016-12-01 00:00:00', 'Email', 100);
```

Here is a basic Select to show whats going on:

```
SELECT  b.UserID
        ,b.Media
        ,b.NCO
        ,Month_sk
        ,CurrentTeam

FROM    ##DataTable b

LEFT OUTER JOIN ##TeamTable a on b.UserID = a.UserID and b.Month_sk = a.ChangeDate

order by UserID, Month_sk, media
```

This gives me a result set that looks like this:

[image: Click for data output]

What I need is for where I have nulls, that it would be pulling in the previous team name that's not null. So in User1 case, those 4 nulls for months of July and August would say Team1 since that was the team he was last on. Same for the nulls after Team2, those should say Team2.

Lead/Lag is close or I'm not using it right. Hopefully with all this code, this makes someone's jobs way easier.

UPDATE:
Lag/Lead gives same results. Still need the nulls to fill in

```
SELECT  b.UserID
        ,b.Media
        ,b.NCO
        ,Month_sk
        ,CurrentTeam
        ,LAG(CurrentTeam,1, currentteam) OVER(PARTITION BY a.userid, changedate ORDER BY ChangeDate) as Lag

FROM    ##DataTable b

LEFT OUTER JOIN ##TeamTable a on b.UserID = a.UserID and b.Month_sk = a.ChangeDate

order by UserID, Month_sk, media
```

Comment: Please add your attempt to use Lead/Lag, so we can debug it.

Comment: Update added at bottom of original post.

Comment: What should happend if your first row's team field is null?

Answer (score 2):

(Moving update notes to end)

I think the easiest solution (conceptually) is to join against all months up to `month_sk` and then filter to get only the last match.  This "feels" potentially inefficient, so you'd want to test it with realistic data volume and if there's a problem then look for something better.  (But "something better" may involve changes to the physical data model...)

So:

```
select userid, media, nco, month_sk, currentteam
  from (SELECT b.UserID
             , b.Media
             , b.NCO
             , Month_sk
             , CurrentTeam
             , rank() over(partition by b.userID
                               order by a.changeDate desc) n
        FROM            ##DataTable b
             INNER JOIN ##TeamTable a
                     on b.UserID = a.UserID
                    and b.Month_sk >= a.ChangeDate
       ) x
 where n = 1
 order by UserID, Month_sk, media
```

Note that in previous versions I used `row_number() over()` instead of `rank() over()`... and you can do that, but if you do then you have to include in the partitioning key any data from the `b` table that could cause a duplication of a row from the `a` table during the join.  Using `rank` ensures that all such duplicates share their rank as they ought to.

**UPDATE** - After I initially wrote this, I deleted it because I thought I'd misread your question; but as I was writing a replacement realized I may have had it right in the first place.  So here it is, with a caveat:

This assumes that the only reason you get the NULL value is the outer join.  If ever the "right hand" table has a row and just a value for a column therein is NULL, then getting the previous value for that column would require further work with subqueries or analytic funcitons.  But even then lead/lag may not work, since they are position based.  (I think something with LAST_VALUE might be more suitable, but will leave the details of that unless it's needed.)

**UPDATE 2** - based on your description of the data model in below comments, I'm changing the query to show an inner join as it sounds like that will work (once you broaden the join criteria) and should be more efficient.

**UPDATE 3** - I did misread your sample data and got the partitioning expression for calculating `n` wrong.  Should be fixed assuming the values from the `b` table are unique.  If not it's still fixable but requires more trickery...

Comment: I actually need those rows where the nulls are. I just need them to have the correct team. Our old table - which doesn't follow any sort of normal forms, has each employee and their team for each month. That is a ton of redundant data because most people don't change teams that often. I wanted to bring some of our tables into 3nf and this is one I wanted to hit. Our existing reports need to be able to pull large groups of data (up to year at a time, across all teams) and list out the data as I have it outputted. I used the Left Outer Join to show how I need the data to end up.

Comment: Are you saying you think you *won't* get those rows with the answer I've posted?  Because unless I'm missing something, you will.  FWIW, while the old table structure you mention may be less efficient, using `(emp,month)` as the key and including all entries is still 3nf (again unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Additional note - you could put a (null-able) end-month on the team records so that a simple range check could drive the join, getting both a compact table and more efficient query.  Like I said "something better" may mean a different data model.  But that does introduce possible inconsistencies (date gaps or overlaps)

Comment: Mark, I copied your code in my project which is still open and I only got 2 results. n narrowed it down to two results, I need all of the data to be in the results with the nulls filled in. 

The original table is more like a flat file than anything. Its all of the data in one place. If I needed to get a list of unique users, I have to do work just to return a list of unique users. I didn't want to have a table that's just users and then a table of what I have but if this proves to be too difficult, I may just do that.

Comment: Then I'm missing something; hang on, I'll look it over.

Comment: Ah, I think I see.  One moment, updating

Comment: BOOM. Let me try that on the actual data tables...but that did what I needed it to do.

Comment: Oh... hey... you know, that may work based on certain assumptions but I think I can do one better... you might want to try replacing the `row_number() over(...)` with `rank() over(partition by b.userid order by a.changeDate desc)`; this more directly says what you mean and won't break if the `b`-table keys change down the road.

Comment: Ill try that as well.

I ported it into my actual reports and its working like a gem. I have done some work with Rank and at one point I suspected I could do it with Rank, I just don't have the breadth of knowledge to know how to get to the end result. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an [APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) and a sub query like this.

```
SELECT 
    userid, 
    media,
    nco,
    month_sk,
    currentteam
FROM
    ##DataTable td
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1) 
            CurrentTeam,
            ChangeDate
        FROM 
            ##TeamTable tt
        WHERE 
            tt.UserID = td.UserID
            and tt.ChangeDate <= td.Month_sk
        ORDER BY
            tt.ChangeDate desc
    ) dataTableWithTeam
ORDER BY
    td.UserID,
    td.Month_sk,
    td.media
```

Answer (score 0):

In this version, I first identify the appropriate "linking" month in the CTE, and then use that as a lookup in the final join. (It got much easier once I realized `Media` and `NCO` played no real part in the join.)

```
WITH cteDateLookup
 as (
    --  Get the ChangeDate for this User/Month
    SELECT
       b.UserID
      ,b.Month_sk
      ,max(a.ChangeDate) ChangeDate
     from ##DataTable b
      left outer join ##TeamTable a
       on b.UserID = a.UserID
        and b.Month_sk >= a.ChangeDate
    group by 
       b.UserID
      ,b.Month_sk
  )
--  Use the cte as a "lookup" for the appropriate date
SELECT
   b.UserID
  ,b.Media
  ,b.NCO
  ,b.Month_sk
  ,a.CurrentTeam
 from ##DataTable  b
  left outer join cteDateLookup  cte
   on cte.UserId = b.UserId
    and b.Month_sk = cte.Month_sk
  left outer join ##TeamTable  a
   on a.UserId = cte.UserId
    and a.ChangeDate = cte.ChangeDate
 order by
   b.UserID
  ,b.Month_sk
  ,b.media
```